# JasperReports 6.x: What to use instead of deprecated JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I update *JasperReports* library from *4.8.0* to *6.3.0* version.

But exporter doesn't have method like as `setLineSeparator`.
`JRTextExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR)` is deprecated.

Settings like this doesn't work:

```
Exporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();
((JRTextExporter)exporter).getParameters().put(JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR, "\r\n");
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(outputFile, characterEncodingProp));
```

Setting as property in jrxml also doesn't work:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator" value="&#xD;&#xA;"/>
```

or

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator" value="\r\n"/>
```

How I can set line separator?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using deprecated *JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR* property we should use *[TextExporterConfiguration.getLineSeparator](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/TextExporterConfiguration.html#getLineSeparator())* method.

In case using *[SimpleTextExporterConfiguration](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/SimpleTextExporterConfiguration.html)* (this is concrete implementation of *TextExporterConfiguration* interface) class the code will be like this:

```
JRExporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();

SimpleTextExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimpleTextExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setLineSeparator("#");

exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporterOutput = new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(file);
exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
exporter.exportReport();
```

---

With help of *[net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width)* and *[net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height)* we can set character width and height.

The snippet of *jrxml* header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ..>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width" value="7.2"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height" value="14.0"/>
```

Comment: I used SimpleTextReportConfiguration.
I also need such methods as 

    configuration.setCharWidth(10f);
    configuration.setCharHeight(20f);

But SimpleTextExporterConfiguration  hasn't these methods.

Comment: This is another question, but I've added info to my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's. Code like this also solved the task:

```
Exporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();
final SimpleTextReportConfiguration txtConfiguration = new SimpleTextReportConfiguration();
txtConfiguration.setCharWidth(10f);
txtConfiguration.setCharHeight(20f);
exporter.setConfiguration(txtConfiguration);
SimpleTextExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimpleTextExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setLineSeparator("\r\n");
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```